# Aspect ratio of video is maintained on one computer but not the other with DirectShow

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I have a `C#` application which plays videos using the `DirectShowNet` [library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). When I debug my application using Visual C# on my laptop, the video is stretched to fit the container's dimensions i.e. the aspect ratio of the video is not maintained. When I load and run my application on a different computer (same operating system), the `aspect ratio` is maintained and black bars are created on the screen.

I **do not** want the aspect ratio to be maintained. I want the other computer to display the video the same way my computer is displaying it.

Why do you think the two computer's act differently and/or how do I fix this?

When I first saw this behaviour on the other computer, I updated that computer's `DirectX` to no avail. The exact same videos are being run on both systems.

**EDIT #1:** Could it possibly be some missing `filter` on the other computer? I assumed the default behaviour of `DirectShow` was not to maintain the `Aspect Ratio`.

**EDIT #2:** When I attempted to use `IVMRWindowlessControl` (`VMR-7` & `VMR-9`), the cast from the VMR to the `IVMRWindowlessControl` kept on resulting in a `NULL` variable. As a result I tried `IVMRAspectRatioControl` with `VMR-7` and it worked on one of the computers. The other computer stayed in Letterbox mode despite the call to remove the Aspect Ratio preservation.

**EDIT #3:** Here is the code using `IVMRAspectRatioControl` with `VMR-7`:

```
int hr = 0;

this.graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();

this.vmr = new VideoMixingRenderer();

this.graphBuilder.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)vmr, "VMR");

this.aspectRatioControl = (IVMRAspectRatioControl)this.vmr;

hr = this.aspectRatioControl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMRAspectRatioMode.None);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

hr = this.graphBuilder.RenderFile(filename, null);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

I am then using `IVideoWindow` to display the video.

When attempting to use the `IVMRWindowlessControl9`, the `this.windowlessControl` evaluated to `NULL` after the `cast` on the 4<sup>th</sup> line. I get the same `NULL` error when I tried it with `VMR-7`. The following uses `VMR-9`:

```
this.graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();

this.vmr = new VideoMixingRenderer9();

this.graphBuilder.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)vmr, "VMR");

this.filterConfig = (IVMRFilterConfig9)vmr;

hr = this.filterConfig.SetNumberOfStreams(1);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr); 
hr = this.filterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowless);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);  

this.windowlessControl = (IVMRWindowlessControl9)this.vmr;

hr = this.windowlessControl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMR9AspectRatioMode.None);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

hr = this.graphBuilder.RenderFile(filename, null);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

I'm not entirely sure how it works, but could it be possible that the second computer does not support `VMR-7` for the `IVMRAspectRatioControl`? The operating systems on both computers are the same, however the first computer (which works) is where I'm writing the software (it has the IDE). The second computer had a fresh install of `Windows`. On the second computer, I also updated `DirectX` as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video renderers can be configured to preserve or not preserve aspect ratio. Configuration method (and, perhaps, default setting, which can also depend on internal mode of the renderer such as overlay/offscreen surface) is dependent on video renderer version you are using, e.g. for VMR-7 you will use [`IVMRWindowlessControl::SetAspectRatioMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s (or, `IVMRAspectRatioControl::SetAspectRatioMode` if your VMR is in windowed mode) DirectShow.NET equivalent/wrapper. VMR-9, EVR has similar methods.

With VMR-9 you will use `IVMRAspectRatioControl9::SetAspectRatioMode`. With EVR it is `IMFVideoDisplayControl::SetAspectRatioMode`.

If you don't want any letterboxing and aspect ration preservation, you just disable it explicitly when you set the video renderer up.

Comment: I found your other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774112/controlling-the-aspect-ratio-in-directshow-full-screen-mode and in it you recommended using IVMRAspectRatioControl. Why would I use `IVMRWindowlessControl` over `IVMRAspectRatioControl`?

Comment: The two interfaces do the same thing, however `IVMRAspectRatioControl` also works in windowed mode. From MSDN: "The IVMRAspectRatioControl interface controls whether the Video Mixing Renderer Filter 7 (VMR-7) preserves the aspect ratio of the source video. This interface is available when the VMR-7 is operating in either windowed or windowless modes. In windowless mode, the same functionality is provided by the IVMRWindowlessControl interface."

Comment: It's hard to tell what you possibly doing wrong - no code is shown. You certainly cannot query IVMRAspectRatioControl9 from VMR-7 and vice versa IVMRAspectRatioControl from VMR-9. Other than that, it is believed to work nicely as documented on MSDN.

Comment: "Control" is windowless when you switch VMR into windowless mode. You don't seem to do it.

Comment: I forgot to post it when I made the edit. See above again, I also added `SetNumberOfStreams`.

Comment: I removed the `IVideoWindow` and it worked with the `VMR-9` `WindowlessControl`. I'm assuming the `IVideoWindow` forced the video rendering mode to `Windowed` which prevented the `WndowlessControl` from working. Either way, it works now.